# logcat in android studio not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

After updating Android Studio to **version 2.2.3**, sometimes(manytimes) it doesn't show logs

Also After re-running application, it doesn't show logs

I have tried **restart button in logcat** but doesn't show effects and have checked all criteria like `No Filters, Verbose, selected emulator and application package.`

**Restarting Android Studio works**

to be more clear , when i clear logs it doesn't show logs again and every time I have to restart Android Studio

can anyone post a solution to this ?

Comment: press Alt+6 on Windows or CMD+6 on Mac.

Comment: not working....

Comment: this issue is solved in Android Studio Version 2.3.3

Answer (score 7):

I know the question is old, but I think my answer can help someone in the future. If you have problems with showing of logcats of emulators, try the following:

1. Turn off the emulator
2. **Rename** emulator
3. Start it again.

It works for me.

Comment: The best solution

Comment: How do you rename the Emulator?  Or do you mean rename the AVD?

Comment: Open Android Virtual Device Manager. Click on the image of pencil next to the emulator you wish to change name, change it and click Finish.

Comment: Tried a lot of things, but only this worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Try this solutions,

**1)** Press Alt+6 twice to restart the logcat window.it will show the log outputs.

**2)** Restart logcat 
   Change the log level to Debug (or anything else) and back to Verbose.
   unplugging and plugging back in the device
   running adb kill-server && adb start-server
   Close Android Studio and launch ddms on the command line.
   Restart Android Studio

**3)** try pressing Alt + 6 to open Log tab.
   Look at the log level:- it must be verbose.
   Restart adb.
   If that doesn't works restart the android studio.

**4)** [image]

In Android 2.2, for some reason, Firebase was selected by default in the dropdown box marked above. So logs didn't drop. I just needed to change it to No Filters. Then it worked.

**5)** Go to Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor (DDMS)
Now you would see Devices tab at the right side, you would see a view menu icon, just click on it and Reset adb
Now you should be able to get the log messages displayed on the LogCat console.

i hope any of these much solution can help you!!!

Comment: ok. i think you have merged all solutions available but i have tried all of your solution either its restarting or DDMS(different case) rather than restarting Android Studio nothing works

Answer (score -1):

1. Frist click on Tool+ Android+ Enable ADB Integration

2.after that click on Tool+  Android+ Android device monitor

3.wait for second..........

or

1.in android 3.0
2.in bottom 6: Logcat option

Answer (score -1):

On the left hand side of the Logcat window, there is an icon named restart. Simply press that icon once would show the logcat messages again.

Answer (score -1):

In some cases it may be a phone issue. you should try restarting your phone or emulator.
It always works for me